# Pull request plugin to merge master into branch

Tags: git, git-merge

Is there a pull request plugin that I can install into **git enterprise** that will allow a developer to click a button and merge master into his branch?

I would like him to be able to do so in the pull request page after he opens a PR.

Comment: Are you referring to GitHub Enterprise? Git != GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, both in [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/home), or [GitLab Enterprise](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/ce-or-ee/).

Both allows you do merge a branch.

But you can also refresh a pull request locally, as seen in "[Improved pull request experience in GitHub for Atom](https://blog.github.com/2018-09-04-github-for-atom/)" in Sept. 2018.

> A Refresh button to pull updated information about the pull request

Again, that won't merge any branch but it will help working on the right content for a given PR.